# swift 3 equivalent for indexAtPosition, urlRequest.url!.isEqual

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, nsindexpath

Hi i am getting following errors while upgrading from swift 2.2 to swift 3

> Argument labels '(atPosition:)' do not match any available overloads"

Below are the following code in swift 2.2.could you guys help me out.

```
private func getIndexInTheLastSection(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int? {
        let index = indexPath.indexAtPosition(indexPath.length - 1)
        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }
        return index
    }
```

////////////////

Comment: Doesn't the compiler make suggestions? Or paste the code into a Playground, then you get detailed information. Alternatives are retyping the function and use code completion or read the documentation.

Comment: In Swift 3 you should use `IndexPath` and then it is just `if let index = indexPath.last { ... }`. – Note that mixing two different problems in one question is problematic. If different people give an answer for each problem, which answer would you accept?

Comment: Martin R : Edited the above question for one answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `isEqual` error with `URL` use `==` instead of `isEqual` to compare.

```
if urlRequest.URL! == strongSelf.request?.urlRequest?.URL {
```

For error `Argument labels '(atPosition:)'`

```
indexPath.index(atPosition: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).length - 1)
```

Comment: In Swift 3 they have use `URL` not `NSURL` and `URL` doesn't have `isEqual` so batter to use `==`.

Comment: Tried using the above the first one for urlRequest worked perfectly.For the second i m getting an issue 'value of type indexPAth has no member'

Comment: i am getting the same error  'value of type indexPAth has no member lenght'

Comment: I am now getting the first  error "Arguments labels(atPostion)" do not match any available overloads

Comment: still getting the same error "Arguments labels(atPostion)" do not match any available overloads –

Comment: @user578386 Can you please add that error in code with more detail.

Comment: that is the complete error i have mentioned..Can you check whethter the above code is getting executed in swift 3 in your mac..i d be much grateful

Comment: Yes i have check in playground it is executing, che this image   http://i.stack.imgur.com/EyRSf.png

Comment: I using swift 3 beta..Let me give a try in the latest version..thanks

Comment: @user578386 Check on Stable version Xcode 8 and let me know.

Comment: atPosition din't work on the stable xcode 8,used of and it worked let index = indexPath.index(of: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).length - 1)